# Add asterisk to label for required fields in AEM adaptive form

Tags: forms, aem

[image]

The given input field - 'First Name' is a required field and is configured in Adaptive AEM Forms. But I want to add red asterisk * to the label for User experience. I can add * beside the label as text but it won't be in red. Is there any configuration in Adaptive form/AEM to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it with CSS, you can try the following

```
.guideFieldNode[data-mandatory=true] .guideFieldLabel label:after {
    content: '*';
    color: red;
}
```

The above would target all fields which have been marked as required in the adaptive form and add the `*` at the end of the field name.

Answer (score 0):

[EDITED]
This answer is to turn a field into a 'required' field.

You need to give `required="{Boolean}true"` in the firstname property.

see the image below

[image]

Comment: Is this for Adaptive forms?

Comment: Yes, its for adaptive form as well, you can enable the required property for the component and can also specify the required message to be shown.

Comment: Just clarifying the issue as mentioned in the description above - The field is configured as mandatory. The required message is also configured. I just want to add a red asterisk along with the field label.

Comment: ok I thought you were asking for how to make the field required. My bad!
@rakhi4410 already answered your query then.